# Helm install, Kubernetes - how to wait for the pods to be ready?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am creating a CI/CD pipeline.

I run `helm install --wait --timeout 300 ...`. But that doesn't really wait, just returns when the "release" status is `DEPLOYED`.

So then I see a few things in  `kubectl get pods --namespace default -l 'release=${TAG}' -o yaml` that could be used:

```
- kind: Pod
  status:
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2018-05-11T00:30:46Z
      status: "True"
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2018-05-11T00:30:48Z
      status: "True"
      type: Ready
```

So I guess I will look at when `Ready` condition becomes "True".

1. It feels a bit wrong thing to do... Everyone solves this so I assume there is some feature of `kubectl` for that, is there?
2. Is this the right thing to query? (See [Kubernetes JSONPath reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/))

   kubectl get pods --namespace default -l 'release=sc8757070' -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}'

Answer (score 12):

Kubernetes already has something to wait on pods (and print a message every time something changes and print a summary at the end).

```
# kubectl rollout status RESOURCE_TYPE RESOURCE_NAME 
kubectl rollout status statefulset app1-hello

# with timeout set to 300 seconds
kubectl rollout status statefulset app1-hello --timeout=300s
```

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for, except it has no timeout (at least the helm doesn't show any such option), so in my case, it waits infinitely. Maybe I should limit the number of restart attempts somewhere?

Comment: Should I set `restartPolicy=Never`? That way, would it stop waiting after first fail? [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) in Kubernetes docs

Comment: Thanks `@Amit_Kumar_Gupta`! This worked. I had to use `kubectl rollut status deployment/<service-name-here>`....it waited until rollout completed.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good option `-n | --namespace NAMESPACE` that allow to wait deployments in different namespaces, for example in `kube-system`:

```
kubectl rollout status deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try this command. It will be rollback and deploy again until it really will be OK deployed.

```
helm upgrade --install --atomic --timeout 300s <<release_name>> ./<<dir_name>> --namespace <<namespace>>
```